# ImageMagick PHP - Distort text and annotate on image

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Is it possible to distort a text and annotate it on an image with ImageMagick (PHP)? Or do I have to create an image from the text, distort it and then paste it on my base image?

I have a coffee mug and want to add text. I want to add a slight arc to my text to have a threedimensional look on my mug.

I tried around with arched font:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/#arch

But in my code example I cannot get it to work because the text is $draw = new ImagickDraw(); and I cannot distort it or use arched font. I always end up with my whole image being distorted because the distortion only works on images like $image = new Imagick('original/'.$id.'.jpg')

Any hints or advice is greatly apprciated. I need a font with a little concave arch like in this example here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13901

I cannot get this to work in PHP.

```
$fontpath = 'fonts/';
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$text1 = $_REQUEST['text1'];
$text2 = $_REQUEST['text2'];

$fontname1 = $_REQUEST['fontname1'];
$fontname2 = $_REQUEST['fontname2'];

$x_coordinate1 = $_REQUEST['x_coordinate1'];
$x_coordinate2 = $_REQUEST['x_coordinate2'];

$y_coordinate1 = $_REQUEST['y_coordinate1'];
$y_coordinate2 = $_REQUEST['y_coordinate2'];

$pointsize1 = $_REQUEST['pointsize1'];
$pointsize2 = $_REQUEST['pointsize2'];

$fill1 = $_REQUEST['fill1'];
$fill2 = $_REQUEST['fill2'];

$stroke1 = $_REQUEST['stroke1'];
$stroke2 = $_REQUEST['stroke2'];

/* Create some objects */
//$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

/* New image */
$image = new Imagick('original/'.$id.'.jpg');

/* Text color */
$draw->setFillColor($fill1);

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont($fontpath.$fontname1);
$draw->setFontSize( $pointsize1 );

/* Create text */
/* Center is important */
$draw->setGravity (Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$image->annotateImage($draw, $x_coordinate1, $y_coordinate1, 0, $text1);

/* Text2 color */
$draw->setFillColor($fill2);

/* Font2 properties */
$draw->setFont($fontpath.$fontname2);
$draw->setFontSize( $pointsize2 );

$draw->setGravity (Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);


$image->annotateImage($draw, $x_coordinate2, $y_coordinate2, 0, $text2);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $image;
```

Comment: You have to create the text as an image with a transparent background and then distort it. Then composite the distorted text image onto your background image. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/ and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#arc. Or you can use my texteffect bash unix shell script via PHP exec(). See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: CONTINUED: See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/#arch for arch and arc. Create the text image on a transparent background and distort it as in these examples. The composite the result onto your background image.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I will need to create another image from my text. I hoped I could avoid this.

Comment: If you are on a Unix system, you might want to explore my bash shell script, texteffect, at my web site http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. Or see the link I specified above. Imagemagick does not create text on a path. So you have to create a text image and then distort it and finally composite it over you background image.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from fmw42 worked best for my problem. I created text as an image with transparent background then distorted and finally composited on another image.